# JavaScript Calculate Button Doesn't Work

Tags: javascript, button, calculator

This script won't show the calculated total at the end. I can't figure it out! Any suggestions? What am I missing? I have the JavaScript code for the tax function too if that helps. Everything works until I get to the final calculation button.

```
<H2>Business Card Pricing Calculator</H2>
<P>
    <STRONG>Type:</STRONG>
    <BR /><BR />
    <INPUT id="Horizontal" value="50" type="radio" name="type" />
    <LABEL for="Horizontal">Horizontal</LABEL> 
    <BR />
    <INPUT id="vertical" value="50" type="radio" name="type" />
    <LABEL for="vertical">Vertical</LABEL>
    <BR />
    <INPUT id="foldover" value="65" type="radio" name="type" />
    <LABEL for="foldover">Foldover</LABEL> 
</P>
<P>
    <STRONG>Options:</STRONG>
    <BR /><BR />
    <INPUT id="cutting" value="10" type="checkbox" name="cutting" /> 
    <LABEL for="cutting">Cutting</LABEL>
    <BR />
    <INPUT id="laminating" value="15" type="checkbox" name="laminating" /> 
    <LABEL for="laminating">Laminating</LABEL>
    <BR />
    <INPUT id="scoring" value="10" type="checkbox" name="scoring" /> 
    <LABEL for="scoring">Scoring</LABEL> 
</P>
<P>
    <STRONG>Tax Rate:</STRONG>
    <INPUT style="TEXT-ALIGN: right" id="tax_rate" maxLength="5" size="3" type="text"
name="tax_rate" />%
</P>
<P>
    <STRONG>Total (Including Tax): </STRONG>
    <SPAN id="total_cost"></SPAN>
</P>
<P>
    <INPUT id="calculate-button" value="CALCULATE" type="button" />
</P>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#calculate-button").click(function () {
    var price = 0;
    var tax = 0;

    var checkedValues = $('input:checked');

    $(checkedValues).each(function (index) {
        price += parseInt(checkedValues[index].value, 10);
    });

    tax = (price * $("#tax_rate").val() / 100);

    $("#total_cost").html(price + tax);
});
```

Comment: Please make a fully-functioning http://jsfiddle.net demo.

Comment: Please post the JavaScript as that is where the bug probably lies.  Be sure to `edit` your post to add the source.

Comment: This is html, which isn't an scripting language. So it won't calculate anything by itself. Please show the JS code.

Comment: Consider using something like http://jsfiddle.net/yp97qz51/. There is no need of using those `p` and `br` elements, you can use `display: block`. And instead of using `for` attribute in `label`, you can place the `input` inside. And uppercase is like shouting (and isn't valid XHTML)

Comment: @Oriol - There isn't anything wrong with using `p` tags that way, the `for` attribute is also perfectly acceptable (and prevents other issues like double-click events triggering), and who cares if it's not XHTML compliant?

Comment: Try to debug your code using `console.log()` calls after each variable assignment and see up to which point it executes as expected. e.g. `console.log(checkedValues);`

Comment: That appears to work (safari on osx): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/083aj343/) - `Total (Including Tax): 61.2`

Comment: I just tried it: http://jsfiddle.net/fnn3qen0/ works fine for me. Do you have jQuery included on your page?